# Web Service -- timeout exception -- (although the sp is returning records in 10 sec.)

Tags: web-services, timeoutexception

I am getting "Time out" error message from one of the web service method, sometimes it's working fine and sometimes throwing error. 
Database sroc. is taking hardly 10 sec. to execute, but still it's throwing timeout error in my application.

One solution is to increase the timeout in web sercice (web.config)

```
httpRuntime executionTimeout="300"
```

Is there any better solution then increasing the timeout?

I am not able to figure out, why is it throwing timeout error when query is executing in 10 sec.
Also sometimes it's working fine and giving me the result quickly.

If anybody encountered the same issue, kindly help me to figure it out and the solution to rectify the issue.

Comment: is it possible your web service is JITing?